# AWS EMR Serverless Spark Job Excepton

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, serverless, amazon-emr

Getting this error when trying to run a simple spark job which reads a json file from s3 and prints the schema.

```
"com.amazonaws.emr.serverless.shaded.software.amazon.awssdk.services.emrserverlessresourcemanager.model.ServiceQuotaExceededException: Worker could not be allocated as the account has reached the service limit on the maximum vCPU it can use concurrently "
```

I am running just this one job with 1 driver.core and 1 executor.core and 1 executor instance. The ServiceQuota is set to concurrent use of 16vCPUs. Can someone explain how might I be hitting the Service Quota limit?

Answer (score 1):

Could please take a look aws best practice?
Here is aws emr best practice documentation about spark configuration!

- https://aws.github.io/aws-emr-best-practices/applications/spark/best_practices/#bp-518-tune-garbage-collector